# Anyone know what this metal lath looking thing is?

Tags: walls, plaster, lath-and-plaster

Demoing a wall and discovered this behind the plaster walls. Looks like it was used instead of wood lath to hold the plaster. Behind it is ductwork for a vent upstairs. Anyone know what this is?

https://imgur.com/a/za6qmL3